# How do I setup the dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(File storeDir) in neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
public class testingclass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(storeDir);
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    // Perform DB operations    
    tx.success();
  } 
 }
}
```

The method has been changed in a way that uses the storeDir variation instead of the string path variation which was explained in the tutorials which I found. I have no clue on how to initialise the storeDir parameters.

Comment: new File(storeDir)